# Преобразование букв другого алфавита в латиницу

Tags: php

Есть ли такая возможность конвертации букв с верхними черточками в латиницу, например: `Á` в `A` ?

Comment: Попробуйте в ручную перевести благо букв не много.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3635511/7485582

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне помогло применение функции codeigniter

```
$this->load->helper('text');
convert_accented_characters($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function letterConverter(string $letter):string
{
 $old_letter = ['Á','Ä'];
 $new_letter = ['A','A'];
 return str_replace($old_letter, $new_letter, $letter);
}
echo letterConverter('Á Ä');
```